# How to calculate the occurrence of specific sentence in a text?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

How can I use below code to calculate how often the bigram is appearing in the example_txt?
Right now I think I retturn whether 'order' appears in the total variable. I would like to calculate the percentage of bigram in total.

So given that we do bigram of total, this is the result:
[('order', 'intake'), ('intake', 'is'), ('is', 'strong'), ('strong', 'for'), ('for', 'q4')]
meaning, the output of my code should be 0.20, as 'order intake' is there 1/5.

```
from nltk import ngrams

example_txt = "order intake is strong for q4"
bi_gram = 'order intake'

#these turns example_txt and bi_gram into bigrams
n_gram_text = ngrams(example_txt.split(), 2)
n_gram = ngrams(bi_gram.split(), 2)


#this is used for extracintg and appending to total and bigram
total =[]
bigram = []
for e in n_gram_text:
    total.append(e)
for i in n_gram:
    bigram.append(i)

#this is supposed to return if bigram exists in total.
for k in bigram:
    for total in k:
        if t in total:
            print('yes')
            print(k)
        else:
            print(t)
```

Edit: new title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Counter from collections module:

```
from collections import Counter
bigram = ('order', 'intake')
counter_total = Counter(total)
perc_bigram = counter_total[bigram] / sum(counter_total.values())
perc_bigram
```

Output:

```
0.2
```

Comment: That's it, pal. Thank you!